# How do you bake the results of a pbr output of a texture into ONLY the colour channel

Tags: baking, shader-nodes, pbr

Basically as described in this video but I would like to know how to do it in blender: https://youtu.be/5ODD6yJH9wQ?si=JO2h6D1owldpQ8__&t=853

tl;dw: I want to know how to take the reflections you get from the metallic aspect of a pbr texture and bake it into the colour channel so that said reflections don't change based on character rotation/movement.